# How to deploy Vue.js app for production base on package-lock.json

Tags: vue.js, npm

I want to build a vue.js app for production with `npm ci`.
Should I put `@vue/cli-service` in `devDependencies` of my package.json and execute

```sh
npm ci
vue-cli-service --mode production
```

Or should I put `@vue/cli-service` in `dependencies` of my package.json and execute

```sh
npm ci --production
vue-cli-service --mode production
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file):

> - `"dependencies"` : Packages required by your application in production.
> - `"devDependencies"` : Packages that are only needed for local development and testing.

If you look at how the vue cli bootstraps an application you'll see a minimal package.json look like:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: I know that the dependencies are required for production, but to build the production bundle I need @vue/cli-service to build it. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build

Comment: I added more of the default package.json file to my answer. Running `npm run build` will already build your application in production mode by default.

Comment: yes but on my production ci/cd pipeline I will have to execute `npm ci` instead of `npm ci --production`. I agree with the fact that `npm run build` will build my app for production but for that I will install all the dev dependencies. Why should I put my`@vue/cli-service` in devDependencies if it is required for production build ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to deploy your app, there are different ways. The one I usually use for my Vue projects is to have a two-fold deployment process:

1. build the app with vue-cli-service
2. deploy the app to whereever I want it to run

It is pretty handy to define a "deploy" script in your `package.json` once you have the deployment figured out, e.g.:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "deploy": "npm run build && ./deploy.sh",
  },
  "dependencies": {…
```

where your `deploy.sh` runs all the neccessary means for deployment. The [Official Vue Documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html) has further pointers towards deployment on many widely used platforms.

EDIT: I guess the answer to your question would be "You run `npm run build` with the build script as defined above". Because that is the way you build a Vue app for production. Further information: [Documentation about Environment variables with vue-cli-service](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html)

Comment: It means that in your prod script you are doing `npm i` or `npm ci` whatever, instead of `npm i --productio` `npm i --production` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install that means that your npm install is for non production.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the issue then, `vue-cli-service build` is the vue way of building an app for production.